# How to receive a message within a specific case of a receive in Akka actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am trying to implement an Akka actor which receives a message and then waits to receive another message without looping. The reason that I am trying to implement it this way is because I require the object received in the first case statement in the second case statement. Below is an example of what I mean.

```
def receive: Receive = {
    case s @ start =>
      receive {
        case e @ end =>
          println(f"Received ${s} and ${e}")
      }
  }
```

I am aware that this might not be the ideal pattern. However, I am still new to Akka and Scala and am not aware of any other way to implement this. All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good way to achieve this:

Create a second receive method that just waits for the second message. Use `context.become` to set this method as the receive function when the first message arrives. The `s` value can be a parameter of this method.

When the second message arrives, it is handled by the new receive method. Use `context.become` to restore the original `receive` method once the message is processed.

You can use the `Stash` support to `stash` any other messages that come when the second receive method is active. When an unexpected message arrives, `stash` the message. When the correct message has been processed and the original receive handler has been restored, call `unstashAll` to put them back on the queue. These messages will be re-sent to the actor in the original order to be processed by the main `receive` method.

It might look like this:

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case s @ start =>
    context.become(endReceive(s))
  // Other cases
}

def endReceive(s: ???): Receive = {
  case e @ end =>
    println(f"Received ${s} and ${e}")
    context.become(receive)
    unstashAll()
  case _ =>
    stash()
}
```

Comment: In the case that I would require more sub cases, should I keep on increasing contexts? Is it efficient to do so?

Comment: I would not worry about efficiency but the design is starting to look odd. Maybe better to catch all the messages and track progress using a state object. Each time a message is received the state is updated and passed back to the receive method in `context.become` and when all the data is there you can do the final processing.

Comment: Is it possible to provide me with an example of how it would look? Thanks!